(Asp.NET C#) Error with executing an update query for a database
I am new to programming, so please be kind. I am working on a final project for C# specifically within ASP.NET. For this project it has been a three part cumulative of CRUD. We are working with a MySQL database of teachers, courses and students.
This is the error I received:
Error I am receiving in Visual Studio: SQL Exception
I have created a controller to handle the update functionality of CRUD. I have tried with creating my SQL query and while attempting to test it within swagger, I ran into an exception. This is what I currently have:
 /// <summary>
 /// controller that 
 /// Updates a teachers information
 /// </summary>
 /// <example>
 /// POST: 
 /// </example>
 /// <returns></returns>
 [HttpPost(template: "UpdateTeacher")]
 public int UpdateTeacher([FromForm] string teacherfname, [FromForm] string teacherlname, [FromForm] string employeenumber, [FromForm] DateTime hiredate, [FromForm] float salary)
 {
     using (MySqlConnection Connection = _context.AccessDatabase())
     {
         Connection.Open();
         MySqlCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
         string SqlFormattedDate = hiredate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

         Command.CommandText = $"UPDATE INTO teachers (teacherfname, teacherlname,employeenumber, hiredate, salary) VALUES ('{teacherfname}','{teacherlname}', {employeenumber}','{SqlFormattedDate}',{salary}')";


         return Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
  }



What is the final CommandText? Note: you should absolutely not concatenate input into SQL - this is just ripe for SQL injection, which is massively dangerous (as in: completely own your database); parameters are your friend - you might want to look at tools that help with parameterization - Dapper or EF for example. With Dapper, this would be less code, not more.

untested, but: using var connection = _context.AccessDatabase(); return connection.Execute("""     UPDATE INTO teachers (teacherfname, teacherlname,employeenumber, hiredate, salary)     VALUES (@teacherfname, @teacherlname, @employeenumber, @SqlFormattedDate, @salary)     """, new { teacherfname, teacherlname, employeenumber, hiredate, salary });

as a side note, I think the problem is probably the uneven quotes around salary, but - and I cannot say this strongly enough: this code is dangerous and needs changing.
